# How can insert back rows on a df by its index position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Imagine i have this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['aa', np.nan, 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', np.nan, 'gg'], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'cc', 'ee', 'dd', 'gg'], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'cc', 'ee', 'dd', 'gg']]).T.rename(columns = {0: 'col_1', 1: 'col2', 2: 'col_3'})

    col_1   col2    col_3
0      aa     aa       aa
1      NaN    bb       bb
2      cc     cc       cc
3      dd     cc       cc
4      ee     ee       ee
5      NaN    dd       dd
6      gg     gg       gg
```

Now i extract the rows where there are nans:

```
df_null = df[df['col_1'].isnull()]
df_null

    col_1   col2    col_3
1     NaN     bb       bb
5     NaN     dd       dd
```

Then i remove these rows from the main df, and performs whatever transformations and ooperations in it:

```
df_no_null = df[~df['col_1'].isnull()]
df_no_null.do_stuff()....
```

Now i take the rows with `nan` values and do more stuff with them:

```
df_null.at[1, 'col_1'] = 'bb'
df_null.at[5, 'col_1'] = 'dd'

df_null

    col_1   col2    col_3
1      bb     bb       bb
5      dd     dd       dd
```

Now i what i want to do is to reinsert back the rows of `df_null` into the original `df`, but i want to put these rows back to their original index position so the result is the same original df with its index intact:

```
   col_1    col2    col_3
0     aa      aa       aa
1     bb      bb       bb
2     cc      cc       cc
3     dd      cc       cc
4     ee      ee       ee
5     dd      dd       dd
6     gg      gg       gg
```

How could i perform such operation in `pandas`?

**NOTE:**

Please note that this is just a toy df, the provided answer should work in a much bigger `df` efficiently and with much more `nans`, so much more rows to insert back in the original `df`

Thank you very much in advance

**EDIT:**

The rows have to be inserted back into `df_no_null` in order to respect the previous operations and stuff performed in this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need select columns by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df_null.index] = df_null
print (df)
  col_1 col2 col_3
0    aa   aa    aa
1    bb   bb    bb
2    cc   cc    cc
3    dd   cc    cc
4    ee   ee    ee
5    dd   dd    dd
6    gg   gg    gg
```

EDIT: For loop solution is possible use:

```
for i in df_null.index:
    df.loc[i] = df_null.loc[i]
print (df)
  col_1 col2 col_3
0    aa   aa    aa
1    bb   bb    bb
2    cc   cc    cc
3    dd   cc    cc
4    ee   ee    ee
5    dd   dd    dd
6    gg   gg    gg
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael!! But this won't work in my case. I need to insert back the rows one by one to `df_no_null`, because if not, all the transformations and stuff done previously will be lost. Since your method replace the whole column, it won't respect those previous transformation. I'll modify the question explaining this

Comment: @Miguel2488 - `I need to insert back the rows one by one to df_no_null` - So you need loop, which are not efffective? I am lost/confused.

Comment: It's ok if there's a loop there, no worries about it ;)

Comment: @Miguel2488 - Now it is a bit guessing, edited answer.

Comment: That's perfect buddy!! Thank you very much! now i know i was overthinking it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following may help you

df = Insert_row_(row_number, df, row_value)

In your case:

df = Insert_row_(1, df, NaN)

df = Inser_row_(5, df, NaN)

Comment: Thank you @Dejene T.!! Is alwys good to have alternative solutions :)